# Click function to search a specific element in a Json object

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I am setting up a part of an application where you can search your zip code and it gives you a re-seller closest to your zip code, along with contact information for the re-seller. I want to make a click function for it with an input box, and the search should only search for the zip codes for the customer (i have customer zip codes and zip codes for the re-seller). I want it to only search through the "zipCode" items in the json file.

I attempted to do a keydown function that shows the items with the selected key, but this lags heavily because there are close to 41,000 objects inside the json file, so I need to do a search where it only retrieves the specified data when clicked so it doesn't freeze the web app.

Here is the HTML file with the script function inside:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Search App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p><br><br></p>
    <div class="container">
        <input type="search" class="form-control" id="search">
        <button id="search-button">Search</button>
        <br>
        <table class="table table-stripped table-bordered table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Zip Code</th>
                    <th>City</th>
                    <th>County</th>
                    <th>Type</th>
                    <th>State</th>
                    <th>Rep</th>
                    <th>Street Address</th>
                    <th>Company City</th>
                    <th>Company State</th>
                    <th>Country</th>
                    <th>Company Zip Code</th>
                    <th>Main Phone</th>
                    <th>Fax</th>
                    <th>Contact Email</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        $('#search-button').click(function() {
            $.getJSON("us-zip-database.json", function(data) {
                var search = $('#search').val();
                var regex = new RegExp(search, 'i');
                var output;
                $.each(data, function(key, val) {
                    output += "<tr>";
                    output += "<td id='"+key+"'>" + val.zipCode + "</td>";
                    output += "<td id='"+key+"'>" + val.city + "</td>";
                    output += "<td id='"+key+"'>" + val.county + "</td>";
                    output += "<td id='"+key+"'>" + val.type + "</td>";
                    output += "<td id='"+key+"'>" + val.state + "</td>";
                    output += "<td id='"+key+"'>" + val.rep + "</td>";
                    output += "<td id='"+key+"'>" + val.streetAddress + "</td>";
                    output += "<td id='"+key+"'>" + val.companyCity + "</td>";
                    output += "<td id='"+key+"'>" + val.companyState + "</td>";
                    output += "<td id='"+key+"'>" + val.companyCountry + "</td>";
                    output += "<td id='"+key+"'>" + val.companyZipCode + "</td>";
                    output += "<td id='"+key+"'>" + val.mainPhone + "</td>";
                    output += "<td id='"+key+"'>" + val.fax + "</td>";
                    output += "<td id='"+key+"'>" + val.contactEmail + "</td>";
                    output += "</tr>";
                });
                $('tbody').html(output);
            });
        });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is a sample of the data in the JSON file:

```
[
        {
            "zipCode": "98001",
            "city": "Auburn",
            "county": "King",
            "type": "Standard",
            "state": "Washington",
            "rep": "Johnson Industries",
            "streetAddress": "1015 S Myrtle St, ",
            "companyCity": "Seattle",
            "companyState": "Washington",
            "companyCountry": "USA",
            "companyZipCode": "98108",
            "mainPhone": 2066228787,
            "fax": 2067631081,
            "contactEmail": "sales@johnsonind-inc.com"
        },
        {
            "zipCode": "98002",
            "city": "Auburn",
            "county": "King",
            "type": "Standard",
            "state": "Washington",
            "rep": "Johnson Industries",
            "streetAddress": "1015 S Myrtle St, ",
            "companyCity": "Seattle",
            "companyState": "Washington",
            "companyCountry": "USA",
            "companyZipCode": "98108",
            "mainPhone": 2066228787,
            "fax": 2067631081,
            "contactEmail": "sales@johnsonind-inc.com"
        },
        {
            "zipCode": "98003",
            "city": "Federal Way",
            "county": "King",
            "type": "Standard",
            "state": "Washington",
            "rep": "Johnson Industries",
            "streetAddress": "1015 S Myrtle St, ",
            "companyCity": "Seattle",
            "companyState": "Washington",
            "companyCountry": "USA",
            "companyZipCode": "98108",
            "mainPhone": 2066228787,
            "fax": 2067631081,
            "contactEmail": "sales@johnsonind-inc.com"
        }
]
```

Comment: I think your question should be more specific.  You have just dumped the code into the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to filter through the data using javascript array filter, after that show the data in table:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Search App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p><br><br></p>
    <div class="container">
        <input type="search" class="form-control" id="search">
        <button id="search-button">Search</button>
        <br>
        <table class="table table-stripped table-bordered table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Zip Code</th>
                    <th>City</th>
                    <th>County</th>
                    <th>Type</th>
                    <th>State</th>
                    <th>Rep</th>
                    <th>Street Address</th>
                    <th>Company City</th>
                    <th>Company State</th>
                    <th>Country</th>
                    <th>Company Zip Code</th>
                    <th>Main Phone</th>
                    <th>Fax</th>
                    <th>Contact Email</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        $('#search-button').click(function() {
            $.getJSON("us-zip-database.json", function(data) {
                var search = $('#search').val();

                var output;

                data = data.filter(function(obj) {
                    return obj.zipCode.indexOf(search) > -1;
                })


                $.each(data, function(key, val) {
                    output += "<tr>";
                    output += "<td id='"+key+"'>" + val.zipCode + "</td>";
                    output += "<td id='"+key+"'>" + val.city + "</td>";
                    output += "<td id='"+key+"'>" + val.county + "</td>";
                    output += "<td id='"+key+"'>" + val.type + "</td>";
                    output += "<td id='"+key+"'>" + val.state + "</td>";
                    output += "<td id='"+key+"'>" + val.rep + "</td>";
                    output += "<td id='"+key+"'>" + val.streetAddress + "</td>";
                    output += "<td id='"+key+"'>" + val.companyCity + "</td>";
                    output += "<td id='"+key+"'>" + val.companyState + "</td>";
                    output += "<td id='"+key+"'>" + val.companyCountry + "</td>";
                    output += "<td id='"+key+"'>" + val.companyZipCode + "</td>";
                    output += "<td id='"+key+"'>" + val.mainPhone + "</td>";
                    output += "<td id='"+key+"'>" + val.fax + "</td>";
                    output += "<td id='"+key+"'>" + val.contactEmail + "</td>";
                    output += "</tr>";
                });
                $('tbody').html(output);
            });
        });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

`Array.filter()` is the function you are after to do the "searching"

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

```js
$('#search-button').click(function() {
  //$.getJSON("us-zip-database.json", function(data) {  
  var data = sample;  //substituted sample data
  var search = $('#search').val();
  var regex = new RegExp(search, 'i');
  var matches = data.filter(value => regex.test(value.zipCode));
  console.log(matches);
  var output;
  $.each(matches, function(key, val) {
    output += "<tr>";
    output += "<td id='" + key + "'>" + val.zipCode + "</td>";
    output += "<td id='" + key + "'>" + val.city + "</td>";
    output += "<td id='" + key + "'>" + val.county + "</td>";
    output += "<td id='" + key + "'>" + val.type + "</td>";
    output += "<td id='" + key + "'>" + val.state + "</td>";
    output += "<td id='" + key + "'>" + val.rep + "</td>";
    output += "<td id='" + key + "'>" + val.streetAddress + "</td>";
    output += "<td id='" + key + "'>" + val.companyCity + "</td>";
    output += "<td id='" + key + "'>" + val.companyState + "</td>";
    output += "<td id='" + key + "'>" + val.companyCountry + "</td>";
    output += "<td id='" + key + "'>" + val.companyZipCode + "</td>";
    output += "<td id='" + key + "'>" + val.mainPhone + "</td>";
    output += "<td id='" + key + "'>" + val.fax + "</td>";
    output += "<td id='" + key + "'>" + val.contactEmail + "</td>";
    output += "</tr>";
  });
  $('tbody').html(output);
  //});
});
var sample = [{
    "zipCode": "98001",
    "city": "Auburn",
    "county": "King",
    "type": "Standard",
    "state": "Washington",
    "rep": "Johnson Industries",
    "streetAddress": "1015 S Myrtle St, ",
    "companyCity": "Seattle",
    "companyState": "Washington",
    "companyCountry": "USA",
    "companyZipCode": "98108",
    "mainPhone": 2066228787,
    "fax": 2067631081,
    "contactEmail": "sales@johnsonind-inc.com"
  },
  {
    "zipCode": "98002",
    "city": "Auburn",
    "county": "King",
    "type": "Standard",
    "state": "Washington",
    "rep": "Johnson Industries",
    "streetAddress": "1015 S Myrtle St, ",
    "companyCity": "Seattle",
    "companyState": "Washington",
    "companyCountry": "USA",
    "companyZipCode": "98108",
    "mainPhone": 2066228787,
    "fax": 2067631081,
    "contactEmail": "sales@johnsonind-inc.com"
  },
  {
    "zipCode": "98003",
    "city": "Federal Way",
    "county": "King",
    "type": "Standard",
    "state": "Washington",
    "rep": "Johnson Industries",
    "streetAddress": "1015 S Myrtle St, ",
    "companyCity": "Seattle",
    "companyState": "Washington",
    "companyCountry": "USA",
    "companyZipCode": "98108",
    "mainPhone": 2066228787,
    "fax": 2067631081,
    "contactEmail": "sales@johnsonind-inc.com"
  }
];
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <title>Search App</title>
</head>

<body>
  <p><br><br></p>
  <div class="container">
    <input type="search" class="form-control" id="search">
    <button id="search-button">Search</button>
    <br>
    <table class="table table-stripped table-bordered table-hover">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Zip Code</th>
          <th>City</th>
          <th>County</th>
          <th>Type</th>
          <th>State</th>
          <th>Rep</th>
          <th>Street Address</th>
          <th>Company City</th>
          <th>Company State</th>
          <th>Country</th>
          <th>Company Zip Code</th>
          <th>Main Phone</th>
          <th>Fax</th>
          <th>Contact Email</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>

      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <script>
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```